# comparing values in two columns of two files - awk

Tags: awk

I want to insert the value of the 2nd column from file2.txt as an additional column in file1.txt DEPENDING, if the value in Ist of file1.txt is less than value in the Ist column of file2.txt
(see desired output)

file1.txt

```
time_stamp ...   values from 1 to n column
0.005000    1   -0.491038 0.251996 -0.681055 0.238940 . . . . . n 
0.010000    1   -0.489565 0.254198 -0.676638 0.244113 . . . . . n
0.015000    1   -0.486287 0.256085 -0.671614 0.249955 . . . . . n
0.020000    1   -0.481431 0.257644 -0.665849 0.256754 . . . . . n
.
.
2.090000    1   -0.198916 0.255882 -0.215078 0.377169 . . . . . n
2.095000    1   -0.201185 0.248889 -0.215151 0.371873 . . . . . n
2.100000    1   -0.202041 0.240778 -0.214463 0.365228 . . . . . n
2.105000    1   -0.200996 0.231328 -0.212667 0.357113 . . . . . n
.
.
.
.
```

file2.txt

```
duration symbol
0.37800  # (from 0.00000 to 0.37800 >>> symbol #)
0.79800  l (from 0.37800 to 0.79800 >>> symbol l)
0.87800  i
.
.
1.04600  aI
1.10400  k
1.17200  t
.
.
.
2.04600  b
2.09400  i
2.10400  I
.
.
.  
3.96800  b
4.01600  I
.
.
.
4.35000  i
4.77200  #
```

Desired output:

```
symbol time_stamp
#      0.005000    1   -0.491038 0.251996 -0.681055 0.238940 . . . . . n 
#      0.010000    1   -0.489565 0.254198 -0.676638 0.244113 . . . . . n
#      0.015000    1   -0.486287 0.256085 -0.671614 0.249955 . . . . . n
#      0.020000    1   -0.481431 0.257644 -0.665849 0.256754 . . . . . n
.
.
b      2.090000 1   -0.198916 0.255882 -0.215078 0.377169 . . . . . n
i      2.095000 1   -0.201185 0.248889 -0.215151 0.371873 . . . . . n
i      2.100000 1   -0.202041 0.240778 -0.214463 0.365228 . . . . . n
i      2.105000 1   -0.200996 0.231328 -0.212667 0.357113 . . . . . n
.
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 2):

You need something like this:

```
awk '
NR==FNR { key2val[$1] = $2; next }
{
    pfx=""
    for (key in key2val) {
        if (key < $1) {
            pfx = key2val[key]
        }
    }
    print pfx, $0
}
' file2 file1
```

I'm sure the math in the loop is wrong but all those `.` lines cluttering and obfuscating your input and output files mean we don't have anything we can easily copy/paste to test with so I'm not going to put any effort into that part and you should be able to figure that detail out given this simple and obvious program structure anyway.

Comment: the `"." dots` are meant to be for continuation, (large text files)

Comment: I know what it means in general but it has no place in sample input and expected output - you should provide a specific testable input file and associated output, not one that we'd need to edit to remove `.`s from to be able to test against or most people just won't bother. Just provide a couple of 5 or 6 line input files, each with some minimal number of fields that demonstrate your problem, and the associated output. That's all.